# Not able to disable servlet response output buffering of Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, out-of-memory

I have a project hosted on Google Appengine, standard runtime.
I have defined a servlet which responds to a GET request with up-to 200kb data. Problem is that the servlet attempts to buffer a very large amount of the data before actually writing out.

I tried to put an upper limit on the buffering by doing,

```
resp.setBufferSize(1024);
```

But this makes no difference. An immediate log of the buffer size,

```
LOGGER.info("Using buffer of size " + resp.getBufferSize());
```

tells me that the buffer is of size 1024, but once the data is written, I again log the buffer size and it has grown to a very large amount depending upon the data written out.

Now, if I increase the output to sufficiently large amount I get an Exception, while writing out that data. The data itself is not stored anywhere, it is generated and written to the "ServletOutputStream" directly.

```
Error for /sizeTestServlet
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcResponseGenerator.addContent(RpcResponseGenerator.java:65)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:644)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:589)
```

Is there some way to disable output buffering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine instances do not support data streaming - they always return an entire response. If you need to stream data, you can use flexible environment.

From 
[How Requests are Handled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled#streaming_responses):

> Streaming Responses
>
> App Engine does not support streaming responses where data is sent in
>   incremental chunks to the client while a request is being processed.
>   All data from your code is collected as described above and sent as a
>   single HTTP response.

Note, however, that for such small responses, as in your case (up to 200KB), streaming may be significantly less efficient and slower than returning all the data at once.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this behaviour?

Comment: I added a link for you.